# How to load a gltf model to Three.js?

Tags: three.js, gltf

I decided to try out gltf format for rendering models in Three.js and I'm using this converter (http://cesiumjs.org/convertmodel.html) to convert the model from Collada to GlTF. It spits out a *.gltf file, however in the examples in Three.js they pass a *.json file. How can I load the *.gltf file or how can I get the proper set of files to load? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `THREE.glTFLoader` which can be found in the [examples/js/loaders](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/examples/js/loaders) directory.

For a demo, see http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_gltf.html.

three.js r.95

Comment: Sorry. The question is what file to pass to the loader? In the example they pass *.json, but none of the collada-to-gltf converters produce a json file. I'm getting files like *.gltf, *.bin and so on, but no json...

Comment: Good question. There appear to be other issues: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/5161

Comment: At least as of r83-r84, the `.json` versions are outdated and not needed. You can use a `.gltf` file directly with THREE.GLTFLoader.

Answer (score 1):

The gltf file is a valid json file as far as I understand it.
I opened a file converted from collada to gltf and it is just plain json.
I put it also through the validator at [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/).
I would suggest to change the file ending from .gltf to .json .

Comment: As of 2016, a `.gltf` file is still valid JSON, but it's not necessary to rename it. Simply use the `.gltf` file's URL as the input to THREE.GLTFLoader.

Comment: @Don McCurdy the file's URL is the file path right?